# How to find the sum of a certain column in a .txt file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

I have a .txt file with 3 rows and 3 columns of data shown below:

```
    1.5    3.1425    blank
    10       12       14
    8.2     blank     9.5
```

I am looking to create a function that allows a user to input a number of either 1,2,or 3 and get the sum of that specified column

The error I receive is as follows:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#41>", line 1, in <module>
     summarizer(2)
   File "/Users/"practice.py", line 
   403, in summarizer
     print(sum(float(col2)))
   ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'
```

I'm just practicing my indexing and am running into trouble when trying to pick a specific column or row to analyze. I have the following code, but get errors pertaining to my index being out of range, or a float object not being iterable

```
def summarizer(searchNum):
    infile = open('nums.txt','r')
    fileContents = infile.readlines()
    infile.close

    newList = []

    for numbers in fileContents:
        numVals = numbers.split('\t')
        for i in range(len(numVals)):
            for j in range(0, len(numVals[i])):
                newList+=numVals[i][j]
            col1 = numVals[i][0]
            col2 = numVals[i][1]
            col3 = numVals[i][2]

            if searchNum == 1:
                print (sum(float(col1)))

            elif searchNum == 2:
                print(sum(float(col2)))

            else:
                print(sum(float(col3)))
```

If a user inputs summarizer(3), I would like the output to be 23.5 since 14+9.5+0= 23.5

Comment: When you submit a MCVE, we need just that: there is no need to include file IO, as your problem is within referencing and data conversion of a single column.  Just hard-code the three strings, make one attempt to add the column, and post the problem per standards.

Comment: probably much easier to dump this into a `pandas.DataFrame` and then do something like `frame.iloc[:,searchNum-1].sum()` or even `frame[searchNum-1].sum()`

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
Among other things, I don't see where you've made any attempt to trace the problem.  `print` your variable values just before you use them -- I think you'll see the problems right there.  `numVals` and `col3` are not what you seem to think.

Comment: @DavidZemens  is it possible to do this without using pandas or numpy? I'm trying to learn the fundamentals/basics of python before branching out

Comment: ... and there you see your immediate problem.  `col2` is a single character.  Back up and figure out how to convert your three input strings into the columns you want.  Until you get that part right, there's no sense in calling `float`, let alone `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

I put comments on the script. You can create three column lists to collect each value in the corresponding columns. Then sum it at the end.

```
def summarizer(searchNum):
    infile = open('nums.txt','r')
    fileContents = infile.readlines()
    infile.close

    col1, col2, col3 = [], [], []   #initialize the columns

    for numbers in fileContents:
        numVals = numbers.replace('\n','').split('\t')    #also remove newline at the end (\n)
        col1.append(float(numVals[0]) if numVals[0] else 0)   #convert to float if not blank else 0 then add to col1
        col2.append(float(numVals[1]) if numVals[1] else 0)
        col3.append(float(numVals[2]) if numVals[2] else 0)

    if searchNum == 1:
        print(sum(col1))

    elif searchNum == 2:
        print(sum(col2))

    else:
        print(sum(col3))    #print the sum of col3

    return
```

Result:

```
summarizer(3)
23.5
```

Comment: in your above code, how would you convert a string to a float? That's the error I'm receiving: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    summarizer(3)
  File "/Users/Downloads/practice.py", line 392, in summarizer
    col1.append(float(numVals[0]) if numVals[0] else 0)   #convert to float if not blank else 0 then add to col1
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.5     3.1415'

Comment: you are missing tab between 1.5 and 3.1415 in your nums.txt.  If you have space instead of tab (\t) then remove '\t' in function split.  It will use the default value which is space.

Comment: appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that text file is perfectly formatted with tabs. Then you need to append each row to a list, and split each value by tabs.

Then you need to get rid of 'blanks' and '\n' or whatever other non-numbers.
Then sum them.

This is how I would do it

```
infile = open('nums.txt','r')
fileContents = infile.readlines()
infile.close

newList = []   # List of lists. Each list is a column
for line in fileContents:
    newList.append(line.split('\t'))

# - Blank must be 0. Let's get rid of \n as well
for i in range(len(newList)):
    for j in range(len(newList[i])):
        if '\n' in newList[i][j]:
            newList[i][j] = newList[i][j].replace('\n', '')
        try:
            newList[i][j] = float(newList[i][j])   # get rid of string entries
        except ValueError:
            newList[i][j] = 0

sum = 0
if searchNum == 1:
    for i in range(len(newList)):
        sum += newList[i][0]
if searchNum == 2:
    for i in range(len(newList)):
        sum += newList[i][1]
if searchNum == 3:
    for i in range(len(newList)):
        sum += newList[i][2]
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation of the "could not convert string to float: '.' " error:**

col2 variable has a string  "blank" (which is not a integer) .
 When you apply float on a string which is not a integer ( in our case float(col2)) it throws the error which u mentioned.

**What your code actually does:**

1.It creates a n*n 2d array and puts all the elements from textfile  to the 2d array.

2.You assign the last element in each column to variable col1,col2,col3

3.You apply sum operation on the last element in each column

**What you were trying to do :**

1.Create a n*n 2d array and puts all the elements from textfile  to the 2d array.

2.Apply sum operation on each column element and display the result:

So ur code is not actually doing what you wanted to do.
I have written the below code which does wat u actually intended to do

### **Solution Code**

```
def summarizer(searchNum):
infile = open('nums.txt','r')
fileContents = infile.readlines()
infile.close

newList = []


for numbers in fileContents:

    # - replace the "blank" string and  with 0  and makes every instance 
    #- float  type  
    numbers =numbers.replace("blank","0").replace('\n','').split('\t')

   # - creates the 2d array of the items from you text file
   for i in range(1,len(numbers)+1):
      newList[i].extend(float(numbers[i-1])) 

   # - prints the sum based on column index u wanted 
print(sum(newList(searchNum)))
```

You can do this easier by using the csv library 
         https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Hope this helped!!